# When deploying function app to azure portal using maven command, how to use existing storage & set/create private end point?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, maven-plugin, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm using maven to create httpTrigger based azure function app., However in a plain context - on use of `mvn azure-functions:deploy` everything deploys properly - However my use case is now different. I'm manually creating a storage with private endpoints and now somehow through my java code I want to make sure that my function app uses the created storage for my function app and I should restrict public access for the this function app. This is something I want to do at the first time deployment of the function app and not as an update after being deployed.

Is there anyway to do this? This issue arises only when you have policy to restrict public access for the function group. If there are no policies, the maven command perfectly works fine creating a function app as expected.

Comment: You should use Bicep to provision (create) all Azure Resources first. After that you need to use ZIP Deploy to deploy only application files. In Bicep, you'll configure your infrastructure as a code. You'll define Storage Account. and Azure Function App with Private Endpoints. It has nothing to do with Maven, Java, or even Azure Functions.

Comment: Please let me know if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create an Azure Function App resource in Azure.

You can do it:

1. Using `az` CLI.
2. Using PowerShell.
3. From Visual Studio via right-click deploy.
4. Manually via Azure Portal.
5. Using Maven (rarely done in that way).
6. Even using Azure ARM REST API (nobody does it this way).

All abovementioned options are not correct from perspective of CI/CD and [Infrastracture-as-a-Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/devops/deliver/what-is-infrastructure-as-code) principles.

---

To deploy your Azure Function App with Storage Account and any other Azure Resources, you need to use Infrastructure-as-a-Code tools:

- [ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) is a native Azure way to provision resources
- [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep) is modern official way to provision Azure Resources
- You can also use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and its [Azure Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest).

---

There is a simple way to start doing Bicep deployments.

1. Go to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).
2. Start creating a new Azure Resource – Function App (Azure Function App).

   [image: Create Azure Function App via Azure Portal]
3. Configure resources that you want to create.

   In your specific case you need:

   - Storage Account (required for Azure Function App)
   - Application Insights (recommended for monitoring)
   - Log Analytics Workspace (required for Application Insights)
   - Functions Premium App Service Plan (required for Azure Function App; must be "Premium" or "Dedicated" to enable Private Endpoints)
   - Azure Function App
4. At the last "Review + create" stage don't click "Create". Click the link "Download a template for automation" and download the ARM template.

From this point you can just use ARM template to provision your resources using `az` CLI.

---

As a prerequisite, you need to have an active subscription in Azure and Resource Group pre-created.

To provision Azure Resources using the ARM template you need to have `az` CLI installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli

Run this command to make a deployment of the ARM template to your existing Resource Group:

```
az deployment group create \
  --name "ARM template deployment" # An arbitrary deployment name \
  --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> # Specify Resource Group name \
  --template-file <path-to-template> # e.g., "template.json" \
  --parameters '@parameters.json'
```

The result of running the command should be like this:

[image: Resource Group deployment]

---

You can also decompile ARM Template into Bicep. The easiest way to do so is to use Visual Studio Code with the [Bicep](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-bicep) extension.

---

You can refer to [Azure Resource Manager QuickStart Templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) to create Bicep from scratch:

- [Storage Account](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-account-create)
- [Azure Function App](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-function)
- [Application Insights](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.insights/insights-alertrules-application-insights)
- [Azure Function Premium Plan](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/function-app-premium-plan)

---

You also can write Bicep from scratch using samples from official Bicep Reference:

- [Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)
- [Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/functions?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)
- [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)
- [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)
- [Log Analytics Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

---

Despite the way of creating a Bicep file, you will have something like this:

```
// template.bicep
param baseName string
@maxLength(11)
param storageAccountPrefix string = 'sa'
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-11-01' = {
  name: 'func-${baseName}'
  kind: 'functionapp'
  location: location
  tags: {
    'hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id': appInsights.id
  }
  properties: {
    // name: 'func-${baseName}'
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'java'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: 'func${toLower(baseName)}acc6'
        }
      ]
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: [
          'https://portal.azure.com'
        ]
      }
      use32BitWorkerProcess: true
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      javaVersion: '1.8'
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
    }
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: null
    httpsOnly: true
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
  }
}

var hostingPlanName = 'asp-${baseName}'
resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2018-11-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  kind: ''
  tags: {
  }
  properties: {
    name: hostingPlanName
    workerSize: 3
    workerSizeId: 3
    numberOfWorkers: 1
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: '20'
    zoneRedundant: false
  }
  sku: {
    tier: 'ElasticPremium'
    name: 'EP1'
  }
}

resource appInsights 'microsoft.insights/components@2020-02-02-preview' = {
  name: 'ai-${baseName}'
  kind: ''
  location: location
  tags: {
  }
  properties: {
    Request_Source: 'IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate'
    Flow_Type: 'Redfield'
    Application_Type: 'web'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.id
  }
}

var storageAccountName = '${storageAccountPrefix}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  location: location
  tags: {
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
  }
}

resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2020-08-01' = {
  name: 'la-${baseName}'
  location: location
  properties: {
  }
}
```

To deploy it, you need to run the `az` CLI command (providing custom `baseName` for your Azure Resources).

"Validate" command:

```
az deployment group validate --resource-group "vlad-dx-rg" --template-file template.bicep --parameters baseName="vlad-dx"
```

"Deploy" command:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group "vlad-dx-rg" --template-file template.bicep --parameters baseName="vlad-dx"
```

The result of the ARM/Bicep deployment to the Resource Group will look like this:

[image: Resource Group deployment result]